# How to best initialize a vector of strings in C++?

Tags: c++

I generally love python's syntax.

v = ["sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf"]

What I currently have in C++ looks like this

```
vector<string> v;
v.push_back("sds");
v.push_back("bsdf");
v.push_back("dsdfaf");
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this? Note that v remains unchanged after initialization. So an array might work too but the problem with array is that I need to also hardcode the length of the array in my code.

```
char* v[] = {"sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf"};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) do_something(v[i]);
```

**EDIT: I don't have C++11. My Compiler is gcc 4.1.2**

Comment: [std::vector<std::string> v { "lol", "lol2", "lol3" };](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61fae5b2c44597e5)

Comment: Exactly what compiler are you using that you "don't have C++11"?  C++11 is just a standard, and different compilers support different amounts of it, but very few support none of it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Comment: Offtopic curiosity question. Why people don't upgrade their compilers to at least a recent version?

Comment: @Gasim I cannot. It's a computing cluster. and if you ask what don't they, the reason is compatibility I guess and being lazy :)

Comment: That's crazy though. I mean at least they should provide gcc4.4 with c++11 support. gcc4.1.2 is like 7 years old :P Anyways to the question. [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) has something similar in the example with the static array.

Comment: @bcrist Tell that to my school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++03 solutions:

Use vector constructor that takes a pair of iterators.

```
char* arr[] = {"sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf"};
vector<string> v(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
```

---

Use an array if the length doesn't need to change after initialization. To avoid hardcoding array length use this function template to deduce size

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t length_of( T const (&)[N] ) { return N; }

char* v[] = {"sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf"};
for (int i = 0; i < length_of(v); ++i) do_something(v[i]);
```

Note that this won't work within a function to which you pass a `char **`.

---

Use [`boost::assign::list_of`](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of_ref)

```
using boost::assign::list_of;
std::vector<std::string> v = list_of("sds")("bsdf")("dsdfaf");
```

Comment: In my opinion all of these are less clear (and by that I mean readable) than the original using `push_back`.  Shorter is not necessarily clearer.

Comment: @bcrist I agree and disagree at the same time. It is immediately clear what the intent is with `push_back` but it is also overly repetitive and verbose if you're initializing the vector with a lot of elements. The array version would be my pick for this case since the OP says he doesn't need to modify the size after initialization.

Comment: True, if there are more than 5 or 6 elements it gets a bit repetitive.    Suffice it to say, C++98/C++03 code is not always as succinct as python.

Comment: I like the length_of one.

Comment: I'd prefer that `arr` were `const`.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you can write:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf"};
```

Comment: Does not appear to work with clang 12.0.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

You can use the *brace initialization syntax*:

```
std::vector<std::string> v { "sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf" };
```

---

> Note that v remains unchanged after initialization.

You can use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (since C++11):

```
std::array<std::string, 3> a {{ "sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf" }};
```

You'll still have to "hardcode" the number of elements, but it's not dynamic anyway, so you don't lose much.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that v remains unchanged after initialization. So an array might work too but the problem with array is that I need to also hardcode the length of the array in my code.

That's not true.  You can get the *array* size the canonical way one does so like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char const * const v[] = {"sds", "bsdf", "dsdfaf"};

    // Only works when array length is known at compile-time.
    size_t const len = sizeof(v) /sizeof(v[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ -Wall foo.cpp ; ./a.out 
sds
bsdf
dsdfaf
```